# How to allow accessing the class?

Tags: java, android, singleton, global-variables

I know, this question asked before but I couldn't overtake this problem. I want to define global variable, so I used extend `application class`. But I can't reach this `subclass`.

I created public constructor as well.

My `superclass` and `subclass` are here:

```
class GlobalVariables extends Application {

    private int sessionid;
    private Locale locale;

    public GlobalVariables(){
    }

    public int getSessionid() {
        return sessionid;
    }

    public void setSessionid(int sessionid) {
        this.sessionid = sessionid;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}

class Application extends Activity {

    Intent intent;
    int sessionid;
    Log log = new Log();
    SQLiteDatabase db2;
    GeneralLog db = new GeneralLog(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sessionid = getSessionId()+1;

        GlobalVariables glb = new GlobalVariables();
        glb.setSessionid(sessionid);

        setContentView(R.layout.application);
    }

    public int getSessionId() {
        SQLiteDatabase db2 = db.getReadableDatabase();
        final SQLiteStatement stmt = db2.compileStatement("SELECT MAX(sessionid) FROM LOG2");

        return (int) stmt.simpleQueryForLong();
    }

    public Application() {
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException : access the class not allowed
```

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Which line you got this exception at?  Sub exceptions usually happen when reflection is used, but there is not reflection in your code sample.

Comment: @Mikhail, I got error when application just begin.

Answer (score 1):

the class extending `Application` has to be `public`

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application
```

Comment: When I tried it, i get this error: The public type GlobalVariables must be defined in its own file

Comment: Why can not you define GlobalVariables class in another file?

Comment: where did you get ClassCastException?

Comment: in your activity, instead of GlobalVariables glb = new GlobalVariables(); try this: GlobalVariables glb = (GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext();

Comment: glb.getsessinid. i got here.

Comment: Shall I use another class file trying GlobalVariables glb = (GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext(); ?

Comment: put GlobalVariables in another file, and in your class Application extends Activity, in the onCreate do:  GlobalVariables glb = (GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24692/discussion-between-breed-hansen-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `public` to your class would solve your problem.

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application
```

Comment: When I tried it, i get this error: The public type GlobalVariables must be defined in its own file

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the scope of the class, it is by default private. You have to make your public so that you can access it from somewhere else.